# How to pass variable into parallel script from text file line by line

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I need to read a file line by line and pass the string as a variable for a script to be run in parallel.

ex:

```
14
43
57
```

is in foo.txt

if I var=$(cat foo.txt) then I can use this $var for inside a script, but how to call parallel to change this variable for each instance running the script?

Comment: What do you want to do? In your example, do you want it to turn into `script 14 & script 43 & script 57` or something?

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want a variable to be set:

```
parallel -a foo.txt 'myvar={}; myscript'
```

But otherwise I think Tom's solution will be what you want most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use GNU Parallel with the -a flag, which reads from a file.

```
parallel -a foo.txt echo
14
43
57
```

It's not the most elegant example but it will just run the same command against all the arguments (line by line) in the text file.  Include the -j flag to specify how many processes to run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

for example: the input - `input.txt`

```
1
2
3
4
```

The command to run `command.sh`

```
#/bin/bash
echo  $1: start
date
sleep 2s
echo  $1 : stop
date
```

Running all together in parallel:

```
➜  /tmp  cat input.txt| xargs -n 1 -P 4 ./command.sh
1: start
3: start
2: start
4: start
Tue May 19 19:03:30 IDT 2015
Tue May 19 19:03:30 IDT 2015
Tue May 19 19:03:30 IDT 2015
Tue May 19 19:03:30 IDT 2015
1 : stop
4 : stop
3 : stop
2 : stop
Tue May 19 19:03:32 IDT 2015
Tue May 19 19:03:32 IDT 2015
Tue May 19 19:03:32 IDT 2015
Tue May 19 19:03:32 IDT 2015
```